# SharePoint duplicate list items issue

Tags: sharepoint-online

In a list there are multiple items with same title . Now I want to loop those same name until new title found and this process with continue till the last item of the list . Finally each name will be printed without redundancy.
Please help me with JSOM code.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you can get an array with the unique Title values from list

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Ensure that the SP.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadNewsData, 'SP.js');
});
```

This is used to get the data from list using REST service

```
/********************************************************************************************
* Function : loadNewsData                                                                   *
* Descritption : This function is used to assign the data to the respective div             *
*********************************************************************************************/
//Get today Date and Year
var todayDate = new Date();
var currentYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
function loadNewsData() {
    var listName = "News";
    var listDispName = "NewsandReferences";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                var results = data.d.results;                    
                var uniqueYear = new Array();                    
                $.each(results, function (index, dataNews) {

                    uniqueYear.push(dataNews.Title);

                });
                //Get unique years using GetUnique
                uniqueYear = GetUnique(uniqueYear);   

                //bind this array to varaible   - uniqueYear
                //Write your code   
            }                
        },
        error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            alert("KeystoneServiceDeskLinks.js:loadServiceData:: " + args.get_message());
        }
    });
}
```

This function used to collect the unique information

```
function GetUnique(inputArray) {
var outputArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    if ((jQuery.inArray(inputArray[i], outputArray)) == -1) {
        outputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
    }
}
return outputArray;}
```

Comment: bit overkill to use a jQuery function ``inArray`` where you can use native JavaScript ``indexOf`` That whole function can be shortened to: ``return inputArray.filter(function(elem,index,self){return self.indexOf(elem)===index})`` which returns an array of unique values (``.filter()`` has been around since IE9)